# Cosecants of half angles

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

> The tangent of an angle is $2.4$. Find the cosecant of half the angle.

My tries:

As $\tan A=2.4=\dfrac{12}{5}\implies \sin A=\pm\dfrac{12}{13}=\dfrac{1}{\csc A}$

Also:

$\sin \frac{A}{2}+\cos \frac{A}{2}=\pm\sqrt{1+\sin A}=\pm\dfrac{5}{{\sqrt{13}}}$ , considering $\sin A=\dfrac{12}{13}$

$\sin \frac{A}{2}-\cos \frac{A}{2}=\pm\sqrt{1-\sin A}=\pm\dfrac{1}{{\sqrt{13}}}$, considering $\sin A=\dfrac{13}{13}$

Adding them gives: $\sin \frac{A}{2}=\pm\dfrac{3}{\sqrt{13}}=\dfrac{1}{\csc{\frac A2}}$

I did same by considering $\sin A=-\dfrac{12}{13}$ then also it gave the same result.

But answer provided by the author is $\dfrac{\pm\sqrt{13}}{2}$ and $\dfrac{\pm\sqrt{13}}{3}$.

So what did I miss? please help.

Answer (score 2):

You found $\sin (A/2)$ but you needed to find $\csc(A/2) = 1/\sin(A/2)$ which is as is in the answer...

Answer (score 1):

You have
$$
\tan^2A=\frac{144}{25}
$$
so
$$
\frac{1}{\cos^2A}=1+\tan^2A=\frac{169}{25}
$$
and therefore
$$
\cos A=\pm\frac{5}{13}
$$
Hence
$$
\sin\frac{A}{2}=\pm\sqrt{\frac{1-\cos A}{2}}
\qquad
\csc\frac{A}{2}=\pm\sqrt{\frac{2}{1-\cos A}}
$$
Plug in the values.

Answer (score 1):

$$|\sin\frac{A}{2}|=\sqrt{\frac{1-\cos{A}}{2}}$$ and
$$\frac{1}{\cos^2A}=1+\tan^2A=6.76.$$
Thus, $|\cos{A}|=\frac{1}{2.6}=\frac{5}{13}$, which says that $\frac{1}{\sin\frac{A}{2}}$ can get four values:
$\sqrt{\frac{2}{1-\frac{5}{13}}}=\frac{\sqrt{13}}{2},$ $-\frac{\sqrt{13}}{2},$ $\sqrt{\frac{2}{1+\frac{5}{13}}}=\frac{\sqrt{13}}{3}$ and $-\frac{\sqrt{13}}{3}$.